# c++ multithread atomic load/store

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model, stdatomic

When I read the 5th chapter of the book [CplusplusConcurrencyInAction](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/CplusplusConcurrencyInAction_PracticalMultithreading.pdf), the example code as follows, multithread load/store some atomic values concurrently with the momery_order_relaxed.Three array save the value of `x、y and z` respectively at each round.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
​
std::atomic<int> x(0),y(0),z(0);  // 1
std::atomic<bool> go(false);  // 2
​
unsigned const loop_count=10;
​
struct read_values
{
  int x,y,z;
};
​
read_values values1[loop_count];
read_values values2[loop_count];
read_values values3[loop_count];
read_values values4[loop_count];
read_values values5[loop_count];
​
void increment(std::atomic<int>* var_to_inc,read_values* values)
{
  while(!go)
    std::this_thread::yield();  
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    var_to_inc->store(i+1,std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 4
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}
​
void read_vals(read_values* values)
{
  while(!go)
    std::this_thread::yield(); 
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}
​
void print(read_values* v)
{
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    if(i)
      std::cout<<",";
    std::cout<<"("<<v[i].x<<","<<v[i].y<<","<<v[i].z<<")";
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
​
int main()
{
  std::thread t1(increment,&x,values1);
  std::thread t2(increment,&y,values2);
  std::thread t3(increment,&z,values3);
  std::thread t4(read_vals,values4);
  std::thread t5(read_vals,values5);
​
  go=true;  
​
  t5.join();
  t4.join();
  t3.join();
  t2.join();
  t1.join();
​
  print(values1);  
  print(values2);
  print(values3);
  print(values4);
  print(values5);
}
```

one of the valid output mentioned in this chapter:

```
(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0),(5,7,0),(6,7,8),(7,9,8),(8,9,8),(9,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(1,3,5),(8,4,5),(8,5,5),(8,6,6),(8,7,9),(10,8,9),(10,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,0,3),(0,0,4),(0,0,5),(0,0,6),(0,0,7),(0,0,8),(0,0,9)
(1,3,0),(2,3,0),(2,4,1),(3,6,4),(3,9,5),(5,10,6),(5,10,8),(5,10,10),(9,10,10),(10,10,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(6,3,7),(6,5,7),(7,7,7),(7,8,7),(8,8,7),(8,8,9),(8,8,9)
```

The 3rd output of `values1` is `(2,0,0)`,at this point it reads `x=2`,and `y=z=0`.It means when `y=0`,the `x` is already equals to 2, Why the 3rd output of the `values2` it reads `x=0` and `y=2`,which means x is the old value because `x、y、z` is increasing, so when `y=2` that x is at least 2. 
And I test the code in my PC,I can't reproduce the result like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that reading via `x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` guarantees *only* that you never see `x` decrease within the same thread (in this example code). (It also guarantees that a thread writing to x will read that same value again in the next iteration.)

In general, different threads can read different values from the same variable at the same time. That is, there need not be a consistent "global state" that all threads agree on. The example output is supposed to demonstrate that: The first thread might still see `y = 0` when it already wrote `x = 4`, while the second thread might still see `x = 0` when it already writes `y = 2`. The standard allows this because real hardware may work that way: Consider the case when the threads are on different CPU cores, each with its own private L1 cache.

However, it is not possible that the second thread sees `x = 5` and then later sees `x = 2` - the atomic object always guarantees that there is a consistent global modification order (that is, all writes to the variable are observed to happen in the same *order* by all the threads).

But when using `std::memory_order_relaxed` there are no guarantees about *when* a thread finally does "see" those writes*, or how the observations of different threads relate to each other. You need stronger memory ordering to get those guarantees.

<sup>*In fact, a valid output would be all threads reading only `0` all the time, except the writer threads reading what they wrote the previous iteration to their "own" variable (and 0 for the others). On hardware that never flushed caches unless prompted, this might actually happen, and it would be fully compliant with the C++ standard!</sup>

> And I test the code in my PC,I can't reproduce the result like that.

The "example output" shown is highly artificial. The C++ standard *allows* for this output to happen. This means you can write efficient and correct multithreaded code even on hardware with no inbuilt guarantees on cache coherency (see above). But common hardware today (x86 in particular) brings a lot of guarantees that actually make certain behavior impossible to observe (including the output in the question).

Also, note that `x`, `y` and `z` are extremely likely to be adjacent (depends on the compiler), meaning they will likely all land on the same cache line. This will lead to massive performance degradation (look up "false sharing"). But since memory can only be transferred between cores at cache line granularity, this (together with the x86 coherency guarantees) makes it essentially *impossible* that an x86 CPU (which you most likely performed your tests with) reads outdated values of any of the variables. Allocating these values more than 1-2 cache lines apart will likely lead to more interesting/chaotic results.

Comment: What if using momery_order_release /acquire, do the cpus flush cache when load the value?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order: Reading with `acquire` guarantees that all preceding `release` writes from other threads are visible in this thread. This may require some form of cache flush, but that's something the compiler and hardware will figure out between each other - on x86 you need no additional instructions (the hardware handles it), whereas on other platforms you may need memory fences (the compiler has to do that).

Comment: "_On hardware that never flushed caches unless prompted, this might actually happen_" Can C++ be implemented on such system?

Comment: @curiousguy: yes in theory, but not efficiently.  Every `atomic<>` load or store would have to flush potentially the whole private cache, or at least everything modified since the last store.

Comment: @Ds.Hale: no, all real hardware that `std::thread` will run across has coherent caches, e.g. using MESI. Reordering only happens "locally" from a store buffer, and on weakly-ordered ISAs (non-x86) from out-of-order completion of loads and/or stores.  Memory barriers don't "flush cache", they just wait for earlier loads and/or stores to complete before later ops can happen. Also having stores become visible to *some* other threads before others is possible on a at least the POWER ISA, but most others are "multi-copy-atomic" and can only make stores visible to all other threads at the same time.

Comment: See also [When to use volatile with multi threading?](//stackoverflow.com/a/58535118) for more about the fact that C++'s memory model was written for cache-coherent hardware.  Also [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223) for the POWER thing of stores becoming visible to some threads before others.  Also [Does a memory barrier ensure that the cache coherence has been completed?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42746793) (no, debunks that misconception)

Comment: *[reading 0s except for your own stores] ... and it would be fully compliant with the C++ standard!*  Not fully unless `yield();` is a no-op.  Otherwise yes maybe, with small loop counts like 10.  ISO C++ says [Implementations *should* make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time.](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#11).  That's not normative, and no definition of "reasonable" is given.  A store-buffer size of 30 entries is totally reasonable; modern mainstream x86 CPUs have more store-buffer entries than that. It doesn't require non-coherent cache, just a SB

Comment: @Ds.Hale: with stores to different variables from multiple threads, observed by loads from another pair of independent threads, IRIW reordering becomes possible where different readers disagree on `x` modified before `y` or vice versa.  IBM POWER can do that in practice.  But this example only uses relaxed reads so local load reordering on different reader cores can produce the same effect.  [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223) explains how it can happen even with acquire loads.